# Count all the calls to add key-value in Hashmap

Tags: java

While going through the HashMap implementation and some tutorials, I thought of this question. But not getting how to solve this. So posting here if you guys can help me out. I want to keep a count of all the calls to add each key-value pair in a Map. It should count the calls to put, putAll and putIfAbsent all the methods too.

Comment: you can wrap those calls in another method and have that method increment a counter variable.

Comment: Op, I'll tell you what not to do: Don't extend HashMap and overridee methods and then call super. Inheritence doesn't work here.

Answer (score 6):

Primarily there are two options,

### Use inheritance

1. Assuming the `Map` implementation you want to track allows extension, then create a subclass and override the required methods.
2. In the overridden methods, do your custom logic(count) and then invoke the `super.` method of the base class(actual method)

Major advantage of this approach, `instanceof` and `generics` compiler behavior will be favorable.

This approach has a major problem, that you need to extend every `Map` class that needs to be supported. It will result is explosion of class.

### Use composition

1. Add a new class that implements Map (per top level related type)
2. Have a reference variable of the actual Map
3. Implement the methods from Map interface
4. In the implementation, do your tracking operation and invoke the map pointed by the reference variable

The major advantage of this method is, there be very few new class.

The disadvantage of this behavior is `instanceof` and `generic` types might not work as expected by user.

### Suggestion

1. If you are planning to use this in some large scale application, then discuss more about the future possible use cases and also abstract the Map creation part to some factory method or even factory.
   This will allow you to encapsulate the implementation details within the factories.
2. Or try some way of doing with method interceptors. Though this can increase latencies slightly, this will not require much change from clients and also avoids maintaining a parallel hierarchy of `Map` implementations.
3. If using interceptors, i don't know the level of detail you can control. Again this will also be complex.
4. Learning these techniques is good. Please don't use them in production code until it's the only possible option.

### Note

1. Define the meaning of `count` precisely
2. Whether calls only from users of this class should be counted?
3. Or, even the calls arising within this class can be counted (like `add` calling `get` to find presence) ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Decorator` pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to add this functionality dynamically to any map.

1. Create a class implementing interface `Map<K, V>` with a final field `Map<K, V> map` and appropriate counter(s) for the stats, and counter field(s) with getter(s).
2. Override methods `put`, `putAll`, `putIfAbsent` to increment counter(s)
3. Implement remaining methods of `Map` interface by delegating calls to `map` field.

Of course, the statistics of `putXxx` operations would be valid only since a map is "decorated".

```java
class PutStatsMapDecorator<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {
    private final Map<K, V> map;  // map being decorated

    private int countPut;
    private int countPutAll;
    private int countPutIfAbsent;

    public PutStatsMapDecorator(Map<K, V> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    // stats getters
    public int getCountPut() { return countPut; }
    public int getCountPutAll() { return countPutAll; }
    public int getCountPutIfAbsent() { return countPutIfAbsent; }

    // override appropriate methods to update counters
    @Override public V put(K key, V value) {
        countPut++;
        return map.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        countPutAll++;
        map.putAll(m);
    }

    @Override public V putIfAbsent(K key, V value) {
        countPutIfAbsent++;
        return map.putIfAbsent(key, value);
    }

    // implement remaining methods of Map interface by delegating calls to `map` field
    @Override public int size() { return map.size(); }
    @Override public boolean isEmpty() { return map.isEmpty(); }
    @Override public boolean containsKey(Object key) { return map.containsKey(key); }
    @Override public boolean containsValue(Object value) { return map.containsValue(value); }
    @Override public V get(Object key) { return map.get(key);}
    @Override public V remove(Object key) { return map.remove(key); }
    @Override public void clear() { map.clear(); }
    @Override public Set<K> keySet() { return map.keySet(); }
    @Override public Collection<V> values() { return map.values(); }
    @Override public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() { return map.entrySet(); }
}
```

Comment: Also called forwarding classes.

Comment: @Alex - Okay, so in the main class, I did the following.

public class Test3 extends PutStatsMapDecorator<Object, Object> {
 public Test3(Map<Object, Object> map) {
  super(map);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Map<String, Integer> copyMap = new HashMap<>();
  PutStatsMapDecorator<String, Integer> psmd = new PutStatsMapDecorator<>(new HashMap<>());
  psmd.put("A", null);
  psmd.put("B", 2);
  psmd.putIfAbsent("A", 4);
  copyMap.putAll(psmd);

After this I called psmd.getCountPut(),  psmd.getCountPutAll() and psmd.getCountPutIfAbsent() to find out the counts.

Comment: Yes, this should have worked for you.  Aside comment, for `putAll` you may need to increment by the size of map being added (if you count _how many_ new entries have been added).  Similarly, you can implement special logic for `putIfAbsent` (e.g., increment counter only if size of the map has changed).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper that implements the Map interface and takes the map where you want to log the calls as constructor parameter. Then you delegate all calls to that map and additionally do the logging:

```
public class LoggingMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V> {
    private Map<K,V> wrapped;

    public LoggingMap<K,V> (Map <K,V> wrapping) {
        wrapped = wrapping;
    }

    @Override
    public xy(...) {
        System.out.println("calling xy"); // log the call
        wrapped.xy(...);                  // delegate to the original map
    }
    
    // repeat for *all* methods of the map interface
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using proxy can help, for example,

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer;
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor;

public class MethodCounter {
    public static HashMap<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
        enhancer.setSuperclass(HashMap.class);
        enhancer.setCallback((MethodInterceptor) (obj, method, args1, proxy) -> {
            if (counts.containsKey(method.getName()))
                counts.put(method.getName(), counts.get(method.getName()) + 1);
            else
                counts.put(method.getName(), 1);

            return proxy.invokeSuper(obj, args1);
        });

        Map<String, String> testMap = (HashMap<String, String>) enhancer.create();

        testMap.put("1", "1");
        testMap.put("2", "1");
        testMap.put("3", "1");
        testMap.put("4", "1");

        testMap.get("1");
        testMap.get("1");
        testMap.get("1");
        testMap.get("1");
        testMap.get("1");

        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        }

    }
}
```

It requires cglib dependency,

```
<dependency>
<groupId>cglib</groupId>
<artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
<version>3.2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

The output of above program is,

```
get: 5
put: 4
```